# Not able to return palindromes

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Here is my code:

```
def palin(n,m):
   palindromes=[]
   for i in range(n,m):                         #to check for all numbers less than r
       str_i = str(i)
       len_i = len(str_i)
       check = 0
       if len_i == 1:                           #for all numbers less than 10
           palindromes.append(i)

       elif len_i%2 == 0:                       #if length is even
           for a in range(int((len_i/2))):
               if str_i[a] == str_i[-a-1]:
                   check = check+1              #increments check by one if the ath digit is equal to len_i-ath digit

                if check == len_i/2:                #checks whether var check has value of half the length of number
                   palindromes.append(i)

       else:                                    #if length is odd
           for a in range(int((len_i -1)/2)):
               if str_i[a] == str_i[-a-1]:
                   check = check+1

               if check == (len_i-1)/2:
                   palindromes.append(i)

       return palindromes

  lst = palin(100,1000)
  print(lst)
  input("WOW!")
```

When I run the following code, an empty list is printed instead of printing a list containing all the palindromes in the given range.
I've tried this code without defining palin() function ad it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with "return" is inside of your "for", so everytime it restarts the return of your function. Try to put that outside the return:

```
def palin(n,m):
    palindromes=[]
    for i in range(10,100):                        #to check for all numbers from n to m
        str_i = str(i)
        len_i = len(str_i)
        check = 0
        if len_i == 1:                          #for all numbers less than 10
            palindromes.append(i)

        elif len_i%2 == 0:                      #if length is even
            for a in range(int((len_i/2))):
                if str_i[a] == str_i[-a-1]:
                    check = check+1             #increments check by one if the ath digit is equal to len_i-ath digit

            if check == len_i/2:                #checks whether var check has value of half the length of number
                palindromes.append(i)

        else:                                   #if length is odd
            for a in range(int((len_i -1)/2)):
                if str_i[a] == str_i[-a-1]:
                    check = check+1

                if check == (len_i-1)/2:
                    palindromes.append(i)

    # Here's the return is outside the for looping and keeps the list values
    return palindromes
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for palindromes just do :

```
palindromes = lambda m,n: [i for i in range(m,n) if str(i)==str(i)[::-1]]
palindrome(100,1000)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot better than what I have written, but can you tell me why my code is returning an empty list.